# SharePoint does not switch view 1 to view 2 on rule

Tags: infopath, view

I created 2 views in InfoPath, View 1 (general user) that is my default view and View 2 (Manager).
I used Form Load and condition:

```
**Condition:** "User is not equal AccountID
**Rule type:** Action
**Run these actions:** Switch to view View 2 (Manager)
```

Then I publish the form. For some reason, View 2 is permanently displayed for the creator of the form, not View 1 as expected.

When I disable this rule, then View 1 is displayed to the creator.

Am I missing something on the InfoPath form? What can be an issue? 
Thanks!